# Responsive Table- 2 columns with header on left side of rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image: Table - Desktop View]

How would I make this table in the image above responsive with css, under 600px?

Wherein the 1st and 3rd columns are "headers" that turn into a simple list view on screens under 600px, like such-

[image: Table - Mobile View]

https://jsfiddle.net/bycxL65r/7

```
<style>
.details td {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: dotted #555555 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.details td strong {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.details {
  border: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  { }
</style>

<div class="details">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 6%;"><span><strong>Led by:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 31%;"><span><strong>Corey Parker</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 10%;"><span><strong>Location:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 49%;"><span>The BGB Studio, 10999 Riverside Dr., Suite 301, North Hollywood, CA 91602</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: transparent !important;">
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 6%;"><span><strong>Dates:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 31%;"><span>April 9 - May 14. Sign up NOW as this class fills fast!</span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 10%;"><span><strong>Requirements:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 49%;"><span><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><span>By application or invitation only. For actors who are auditioning consistently. </span></span><span style="font-size: 12pt;">There are no make-ups for this 6-week class. <a style="color: #cd2427;" href="http://bramongarciabraun.com/cancellation-policy/">(Cancellation Policy)</a></span></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 6%;"><span><strong>Duration:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 31%;"><span><span>6 weeks. Mondays, 7pm - 10pm.</span></span><span>
</span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 10%;"><span><strong>Cost:</strong></span></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 49%;"><span>$480 for the entire 6-week program. 2 installments ($270 &amp; $210).
</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a case where toggling two different markup structures for mobile and desktop might be better than doing a dramatic transform on a table.

Comment: @isherwood actually that's the very thing I'm trying to avoid. The information in the markup gets updated frequently and I'd like to only have to update it in one place.

Comment: You need to alter/modify the HTML in order to add a `data` attribute to the `<td>`'s so you can then target them with CSS using the `content` property and the `::before` pseudo-element. Look at lines `18` to `23` in the HTML panel in this Pen: https://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/IlECr?editors=1100